# Possible to create 3 Tables and then Query all 3 Tables?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to GCP and I just want to understand if I am on the right track here...

So, if I understand correctly, I create ONE instance and then I can create SQL Tables within that ONE instance?

Then, can I access the data via a secure URL and issue SQL Queries for all tables?

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks

Comment: Which product are you using Compute Engine or Cloud SQL?

Comment: Cloud SQL would be the service I'd be using

Comment: Then the answer is yes you can create any number of tables and query them using a SQL client or software. You cannot use a secure URL to access data (meaning an HTTPS web browser).

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley

If you can't access a secure URL to access data then how do you connect to a Google Instance with an app or other? Just curious.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart